# Continuous time Markov chain. proportion of time spent in state i

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

If a question asks for the proportion of time spent in a specific state is this the same as the stationary distribution or something else? For continuous time Markov chain with finite state space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that'll be the steady state distribution of the state. This happens because of the regenerative structure of the CTMC and thus long time fraction of time spent in a state becomes equal to its steady state probability. So, it is not special for CTMC's but is true for all kind of regenerative processes.